# jQuery file is not found in node.js + Express app deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, heroku

I have a node.js + Express + express-handlebars app deployed on Heroku. When running the app the console shows that the jquery file was not found (404) error. This creates a cascading effect and resulting dependant libraries like Bootstrap, Datatables etc fail.

The following is my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "test-node",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test node",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/username/repo.git"
  },
  "author": "Neeraj Jadhav",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/username/repo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/username/repo",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sendgrid": "^2.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.28",
    "npm": "1.4.9"
  }
}
```

The following is the screenshot of my node js project folder structure.

[image: node js project structure]

It is unable to find the jquery-1.12.1.min.js

[image: error on console]

In my app.js I moved the line of code referencing the static files above everyone else, but it still does not work. If I open the jquery Heroku link in a new tab and add public before js, like this: https://admin-violet.herokuapp.com/public/js/jQuery-1.12.1.min.js , it shows the same error.

[image: app.js code]

Any idea on why it is unable to find the jquery file? I have deployed node js projects on Heroku before but never faced this issue.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lowercase letters for heroku and node, note the error is looking for *jQuery*, just point it to *jquery* and you should be good.

**Relevant Docs:**

[Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#stick-with-lowercase)

Some languages encourage filenames that match class names, like MyClass and ‘MyClass.js’. Don’t do that in node. Instead, use lowercase files:

```
let MyClass = require('my-class');
```

> Node.js is the rare example of a Linux-centric tool with great cross-platform support. While OSX and Windows will treat ‘myclass.js’ and ‘MyClass.js’ equivalently, Linux won’t. To write code that’s portable between platforms, you’ll need to exactly match require statements, including capitalization.
>   The easy way to get this right is to just stick with lowercase filenames for everything, eg ‘my-class.js’.

Answer (score -3):

In your command line tool - try to restart the Heroku server. `heroku restart` or try to read the logs `heroku logs -t` the "-t" is a flag for tail will show you where it errors out on the server side within Heroku.